# Convertir string a double especificando separador de decimales

Tags: .net

favor su colaboración con lo siguiente, quiero convertir un string a double pero especificando el separador de decimales, ejemplo

```
String a = "123,45";
String b = "987.65";
//Requiero uno conversión especificando el separador, no se algo como lo siguiente
double ad = Double.Parse(a,",");
double bd = Double.Parse(b,".");
```

Con preferencia que sea en vb.net

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta la encontre en este link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Como podran observar se define:

```
NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

y en la conversión se la realiza con:

```
string value = "123,23";
Double k = Convert.ToDouble(value, provider));
```

Donde value es el string que se desea convertir.

Saludos